# Query Optimization With Multiple Tables and Big Data

Tags: mysql

I am doing a project for my Master Degree where I have a 500GB of MySQL database. My project has to do with StackOverflow thus why it is so big. I need to optimize a select query because it takes a minute to run it and it is too slow in my opinion especially I am making a GUI using Java and simply waiting a minute is not great idea. This is the table I have and relevant info:

Table: Tags with 22 222 747 records.

[image: Tags Table]

Index for Tags.

[image: Tags Index]

Table: Links with 8 117 955 records. Index on lid and aid.

[image: Links Table]

Index for Links

[image: Links Index]

Table: Answers with 14 401 786 records. Index on aid and qid.

[image: Answers Table]

Index for Answers

[image: Answers Index]

Table: Questions with 7 495 155 records.

[image: Questions Table]

Index for Questions.

[image: Questions Index]

The idea is I collect redirected links that people post in the answers and my tool would recommend some links depending what the user wants. The user can specify many tags but for simplicity let's assume 2 tags. This is the query I am using:

```
SELECT questions.title, links.url 
FROM questions, answers, links, tags 
WHERE questions.qid = tags.qid 
  AND answers.qid = questions.qid 
  AND answers.aid = links.aid 
  AND (tags.tag = 'php' OR tags.tag = 'mysql') 
GROUP BY tags.qid, links.url HAVING count(*) = 2;
```

This is the picture of the Explain of the query above:

[image: Explain]

If the user would ask 3 or more tags then I would add 1 more OR condition and count(*) = the number of tags.

I am not a pro of MySQL so I am sure there can be ways to improve it. I created indexes for qid, aid and tag where the length is 10. I would prefer to avoid altering the table if possible unless there is no way to avoid it.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Post your data model including indexes please. Also post the execution plan (explain plan) so that we can see what the query actually does

Comment: Do you just want all the indexes from all tables that I have?

Comment: All the tables related to the query (so all 4)

Comment: Do you need anything else?

Comment: It is tradition (and also in the intro manual from SO) to not use images for code etc since they can not be indexed by search engines. Also reading and copy/paste from them is just not handy (you are new, someone with a few 100 points just gets down voted when they do what you did in this question). So out of habit I was pretty much ignoring your screenshots.

Comment: Also need your real index statements (or show index from table) to see how the indexes are created (multi column, single column)

Comment: I see. I do not know how to put the table information efficiently so I thought images would be the best. I posted the index info.

Comment: Show create table will get you copy/paste-able content :)

Comment: "*not know how to put the table information efficiently*... Well in the same toolbar that allowed you to embed images there is **{}**. Paste in some text, highlight that text, and click **{}** it will move the text 4 characters to the right, and in the preview you will see that it is laid out as a code/script block. Also fairly easy to learn these things if you use the site help in the footer. So instead of making images of text, just use the text and paste it in.

Answer (score 0):

At this moment your query has to process >1.6mln rows. This might be reduced with a multi column index on the tags table:

```
CREATE INDEX tags2 ON tags (tags, qid);
```

Or alternative (depends on the data which way works best, and I can't test that without the real database):

```
CREATE INDEX tags3 ON tags (qid, tag);
```

The downside of many indexes is that insert and updates become slower. To prevent that from happening, remove indexes which are not used according to the plans.

Other indexes which might help are:

```
CREATE INDEX ans1 ON answers(qid,aid);
```

Or

```
CREATE INDEX ans2 ON answers(aid,qid);
```

Comment: I do not plan to insert or update my database. I will test those indexes.